# Unit of Work example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I read this page: http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/
It's very interesting. The author has a very good knowledge of the topic but he's not willing to provide the community with samples.

I would like to use the "Injected Unit of Work Factory" pattern but I do not know how to implement the Repositories. For instance, I do not know where I should create the DbContext and where to call the SaveChanges();

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Entity framework and the DB context encapsulates the Unit of Work pattern, there is no need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Please read the linked page before to add an answer or a comment. I know there are hundreds ways to implement UoW and Repository patterns but my question is very specific to the "Injected Unit of Work Factory".

Comment: You could simply implement the Unit of Work pattern as described in this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application but then simply add a factory pattern to create your UoW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think hard about whether you should be implementing another implementation of the Unit of Work pattern, given that, as others have said, a `DbContext` does a pretty good job of implementing the pattern. I've been in codebases where people have added extra abstractions, and often you find that the abstractions don't benefit you because they add at least as many problems as they solve. Consider leaving off until it's needed.

But, the answer to your question would be;

- figure out where the 'entry point' of your app is. For an MVC project, for example, it's a Controller.
- Use dependency injection to create your entry points/controllers;

  ```
  public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService)
  {
      this.customerService = customerService;
  }
  ```
- use the services as appropriate;

  ```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
      var model = this.customService.GetCustomer(id);
      return View(model);
  }
  ```
- set up dependency injection to give your unit of work the right lifetime;

  ```
  kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
  kernel.Bind<ICustomerService().To<CustomerService>();
  kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerReposotory>();
  ```

Then when you create a CustomerController, it requests a CustomerService; that requests an ICustomerRepostory, which requests IUnitOfWork, which is given the same context across the entire request.

It's not necessarily an approach I'd recommend, but it's the answer to the question!